# Intel Conda installation on macbook pro : changing the name of environment from "root" to "base"

Tags: python, sonoma, environment-variables, package-management, intel

I have recently installed Intel conda on my macbook pro Sonoma and I have an issue when I list the different available environments of conda :

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
2022.2.0                 /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/envs/2022.2.0
root                  *  /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest
```

I would like to rename the "`root`" environment" to "`base`" as I had before this new installation.

I tried to clone the "`root`" to a new environment called "`base`" and remove after "root" but I have an error message when I try to remove the "`root`" environment. I guees this is caused by the fact that "`root`" is the main component of my Intel conda installation.

So I would like to find a strategy to circumvent this error and get a classical "base" environment, that could appear with a " `$ conda env list` " :

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest
2022.2.0                 /opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/envs/2022.2.0
```